# the amount of/how much harmful gases was/were

Tags: grammar

**Context:** This is an IELTS writing test, they give us a chart showing how many tons of air pollutants released in the UK throughout the years.

1. The chart illustrates **how much pollutants were** emitted into the atmosphere in 1970.
2. The chart illustrates **the amount of pollutants** emitted into the atmosphere in 1970.

I know the rule is: amount/much + uncountable nouns and number/many + countable nouns.
However, in these two cases, I want to emphasize that there are several different types of pollutants, but also, I certainly can't say [how many/the number of] pollutants either because it sounds like I'm counting the number of types of pollutants, not what I want which is the weight of them. So I'm in a dilemma right here. Are the two sentences correct?

Comment: Hi. So, you want to say that there are "several different types of pollutants", but then you say that if you use "many" you say "it sounds like I'm counting the number of types of pollutants".  But aren't these the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Pollutants, in this case, can be the sum total of all polluting substances or it can be a number of specific polluting substances. so all these are correct but have different meanings...

"the amount of pollutants emitted" - overall quantity of many polluting substances (this fits your meaning best).

"the amount of pollutant emitted", "how much pollutant was emitted" - overall quantity of a polluting substance. This could mean all polluting substance but probaly not. Without context it would be slightly ambiguous

"how many pollutants were emitted" - number of types of pollutant.